# Modular Exponentiation

Tags: c, modulus, exponentiation

In C/C++ how can I calculate `(a^b)%m` where `b` does not fit into 64 bits? In other words, is there a way of calculating the above value using `b%m` instead of `b`?

And is there any algorithm that can compute the above result in `O(log(b))` time or `O(log(b%m))` time?

Comment: This seems more like a math question.

Comment: Try http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you mean where b doesn't fit into 64 bits? The usual exponentiation algorithm has you accumulating a result by multiplying by a if the next bit of b is set and then squaring. This seems pretty easy for large b, it's large a and m that is hard.

Comment: Yes, and let us say b is a Fibonacci number, and a & m< 10^9. How can I find the (a^b)%m. Given that I am using log(n) matrix exponentiation algorithm for finding b. How should I used the intermediate b values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), if `a` and `m` are coprime:

`ab mod m = ab mod phi(m) mod m`

so if `b` is large, you can use the value `b % phi(m)` instead of `b`. `phi(m)` is [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), which can be easily calculated if you know the prime factorization of `m`.

Once you've reduced the value of `b` in this way, use [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) to compute the modular exponentiation in `O(log (b % phi(m)))`.

Comment: to nit-pick: this is only true if a and m are coprime.

Comment: @Henrik: That means it will work even if m is prime and a < m. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Henrik: Right, I forgot about that, thanks. sabari: Yes, it will work in that case.

Comment: Carmichael's function is a generalization of Totient for non-coprime numbers. See my answer to the exact same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272437/calculating-abmod/11272606#11272606

Comment: @ViktorLatypov: I don't see how Carmichael's function helps, as it still requires `a` and `m` to be coprime.