# how to calculate a^(b^c) mod n?

Tags: c, algorithm, math, number-theory

Can someone tell me the efficient way to solve this problem ?

## a<sup>b<sup>c</sup></sup> mod m

#### a, b, c, and m are 32 bit int

where **m is not a prime number** and **a is not coprime to m**?I've looking for the answer, but haven't found it
There are some answered questions that familiar with this question, but none of them can explain my problem. Remember if

## a<sup>b<sup>c</sup></sup> mod m != a<sup>bc</sup> mod m

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place for this question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because http://cs.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this question.

Comment: It's not really a duplicate of the pow question. The common problem is computing this without overflow.

Comment: Thanks hatchet for spotting the main issue. +1

Comment: @anatolyg this question is about [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) so it's not a duplicate of the other question

Comment: So what you want is not just a ModPow function, but a ModPowPow function.

Comment: some other duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496182/calculating-powa-b-mod-n http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287144/modulus-power-of-big-numbers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448658/modular-exponentiation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935862/modular-exponentiation

Comment: Sorry - missed the part about `b^c` being too big!

Comment: thanks for the comment, but most of the questions ask a^b mod n instead of a^b^c mod n. Those are two different things. I think, we have to calculate b^c, but in what way? There must be some way to simplify it. If n is a prime number and a is coprime to n, we can use Euler's totient function. But if n is not prime, this is my problem which i ask to you :)

Comment: @mfrazi I voted-up, I really like part `a is not coprime to m`. All other questions (or just answers) quietly assumed relatively prime of numbers. However, I describe solution to this problem in other question (in which it fits). Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27465498/2349936). I hope it will be helpful and I was understandable.

Comment: Generally I don't understand, why it was closed. I agree [finding a^b^c^… mod m](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223313/finding-abc-mod-m) is same question, but without (a moment ago) any answer, if a,b aren't co-prime! And other answer seems reasonable, if there was no answer to this question. All repeat schematic solution to case `gcd(a,m)=1`. Even here can be seen this case without any tips to solve this problem. It is so unusual that it seems even merit a separate thread.