# CSES exponentiation 2 problem in handling mod=1000000007(10^9+7)

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
using ull = unsigned long long;
#define tt ull tt; cin>>tt; while(tt--)

ull calExpo(ull x, ull y, ull mod){
    ull res=1;
    while(y>0){
        if(y&1){
            res=(res*x)%mod;
        }
        y=y>>1;
        x=(x*x)%mod;
    }
    return res;
}

void solve(void){
    tt{
        ull x,y,z;
        cin>>x>>y>>z;
        ull mod=1000000007;
        ull t= calExpo(y,z,mod-1); // doubt is in this line
        cout<<calExpo(x,t,mod)<<endl;
    }
}

int main(void){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    
    // #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    //  freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    //  freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    // #endif

    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

i wrote code for CSES problem https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1712/
(problem description in short: give n test cases for each n there are 3 integer values a,b,c we have to calculate a^b^c (a to the power b and b to the power c) given mod=10^9+7 )
i was getting error when i passed only (mod) as third argument while calling function (calExpo) for first time (in line ull t= calExpo(y,z,mod-1); ) then i passed mod-1 and it passed all test cases .
please tell me what is the reason behind that?

Comment: `#define tt ll tt; cin>>tt; while(tt--)` probably gets you an instant downvote.

Comment: Does not compile.  Non-standard include.  Does not define `ll`.  Could be running into problems because of ill-advised `using namespace std;`.  Doesn't mention the input to use.  Doesn't mention the expected output from the input to use.  Doesn't mention the actual output from the input to use.

Comment: Duplicate? Concerning modular exponentiation, you will find useful information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448658/modular-exponentiation. If P is prime, `phi(P)=P-1` !

Comment: Sorry I just removed my template,  that ll t; remained unnoticed ..sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

The reason why taking `mod-1` is correct is because of Fermat's little theorem:

[image: a^p \equiv a \mod p]

Therefore:

[image: a^{r\cdot(p-1) + q} \equiv a^q \mod p]

In your case you are representing `b`^`c` as `r * (p-1) + q` which is essentially taking it modulo `p-1`.

Comment: Something is really weird with that font for the equations on chrome on windows. Edit: I see it does not work in the StackOverflow dark theme.