# Modulus of Power

Tags: language-agnostic

I had a problem that of calculation of `a^b mod m` , is 
possible using modular exponentiation but the problem i am having is that the b I have is of very large value , `b > 2^63 - 1` so could we modify the modular exponentiation code

```
function modular_pow(base, exponent, modulus)
    result := 1
    while exponent > 0
        if (exponent mod 2 == 1):
           result := (result * base) mod modulus
        exponent := exponent >> 1
        base = (base * base) mod modulus
    return result
```

to accomodate for such a large `b`

or is it correct that `a^b mod m` is equal to `(a^(b mod m)) mod m` ?

Comment: Your question is better asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/ But I do recall there is an equality like that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11272606/1180785

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct that `a^b mod m` = `a^(b  mod phi(m)) mod m`, where phi(m) is [Euler totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)

Your code is correct too (if types are long enough to represent all values)

You may also combine two methods