# Calculate (a^b)%c where 0<=a,b,c<=10^18

Tags: c++, math, modular-arithmetic

How can I calculate `(a ^ b) % c`, where `0 <= a, b, c <= 10^18`.
Here, `(a ^ b)` means `a` to the power `b`, not `a xor b`.

My current code for the problem is:

```
unsigned long long bigMod(unsigned long long b,
                          unsigned long long p,
                          unsigned long long m){
    if(b == 1) return b;
    if(p == 0) return 1;
    if(p == 1) return b;

    if(p % 2 == 0){  
        unsigned long long temp = bigMod(b, p / 2ll, m);
        return ((temp) * (temp) )% m;
    }else return (b  *  bigMod(b, p-1, m)) % m;
}
```

For this input:

```
a = 12345 b = 123456789 and c = 123456789012345
```

the expected output should be:

```
59212459031520
```

Comment: [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) might be a useful starting point. It's not too hard to add modulus to the formula, if you observe that `(a**b)%c == ((a%c)**b)%c)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calculating a^b mod c](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26722/calculating-ab-mod-c).

Comment: I was trying ((a%m)*(b%m))%m but may be my approach is not right.

Comment: @AndrewMorton may be I tried that approach isn't correct for this limit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating pow(a,b) mod n](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496182/calculating-powa-b-mod-n)

Comment: [Calculating (a^b)%MOD](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11272437/995714). For a and b that are 64 bits, use [`__int128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) for the intermediate multiplication. If it's not available, write your own 128-bit multiplication. Reference: [Fastest way to calculate a 128-bit integer modulo a 64-bit integer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2566010/995714), [Most accurate way to do a combined multiply-and-divide operation in 64-bit?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8733178/995714)

Comment: @AbuHanifa The approach ((a%m)^(b%m)%m fails because the exponent must be modulo'ed by phi(m), where phi is Euler's totient function. If m is prime, then phi(m)=m-1 and you could reduce as ((a%m)^(b%(m-1)))%m.

Comment: @NicoSchertler thanks for tips. very helpful

Comment: "0 <= a, b, c <= 10^18" certainly also needs `c > 0`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with temp*temp (long long overflow). You can omit this problem using algorithm of fast mod power to multiply them mod m. Here You have working code:

```
unsigned long long bigMultiply(unsigned long long b,unsigned long long p, unsigned long long m)
{
  if(p == 0 )return b;
  if(p%2 == 0)
  {  
     unsigned long long temp = bigMultiply(b,p/2ll,m);
     return ((temp)+(temp))%m;
  }
  else
    return (b  +  bigMultiply(b,p-1,m))%m;
}    
unsigned long long bigMod(unsigned long long b,unsigned long long p, unsigned long long m)
{

  if(b == 1)
    return b;
  if(p == 0 )return 1;
  if( p == 1)return b;
  if(p%2 == 0)
  {  
     unsigned ll temp = bigMod(b,p/2ll,m);
     return bigMultiply(temp,temp,m);
  }
  else
    return (b  *  bigMod(b,p-1,m))%m;
}
```

Comment: Trouble with some corner cases: `bigMod(1, p, 1)` is 1 and should be 0.  Suggest `if(b == 1) return b%m;`  Similar for `if(p == 0 )return 1;` --> `if(p == 0 )return 1%m;` to handle `m==1` and `if( p == 1)return b;` --> `if( p == 1)return b%m;` to handle `b >= m`.

Comment: I am quite certain `b  *  bigMod(b,p-1,m)` can readily overflow.  That aside, this code is very nice yet has some limitations: `(temp)+(temp)` can still overflow when `m > ULLONG_MAX/2`, yet that is beyond OP's `c <= 10^18`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code in c++:

```c++
long long power(long long a, long long b, long long c)
{
    if (b==0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if (b % 2 == 0)
    {
        long long w = power(a, b/2, c);
        return (w*w) % c;
    }
    else
    {
        int w = power(a, b-1, c);
        return (a*w) % c;
    }
}
```

It has logarithmic complexity.

Comment: it doesn't work if a and b are both 64 bits, as `w*w` needs a 128-bit type to store