# fast way to calculate a^(b!)mod(c)

Tags: c++, algorithm

Here is what I've tried so far. I don't know what is wrong with this code, but it's giving the wrong answer for large cases: x,y,n > 10^5.

```
#include <stdio.h>
long long factorial(long long N)
{
  long long product = 1;
  for ( long long j=1;j<=N;j++)
    product *= j;
  return product;
}
long long power(long long x, unsigned long long y, long long p) 
{ 
    long long res = 1;      // Initialize result 

    x = x % p;  // Update x if it is more than or  
                // equal to p 

    while (y > 0) 
    { 
        // If y is odd, multiply x with result 
        if (y & 1) 
            res = (res*x) % p; 

        // y must be even now 
        y = y>>1; // y = y/2 
        x = (x*x) % p;   
    } 
    return res; 
} 
int main()  
{  
   long long A,B,C,test;
   scanf("%lld",&test);
   for (long long i = 0;i<test;i++)
   {
       scanf("%lld %lld %lld",&A,&B,&C);
        long long fa = factorial(B);
        long long res = power(A,fa,C);
        printf("%lld \n",res);
   }
   return 0;  
}
```

Any help or walkthrough will be appreciated.

Comment: You should tag the language this is written in.

Comment: Calculating `b!` that way won't help. This is related to modular arithmetic. So, all we would need in the end is some value between `0` and `c-1`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: you can fit in -> you can definitely fit in

Comment: Have a read about how to do this in a memory efficient manner (so you won't experience overflow given your modulus isn't enormous): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Memory-efficient_method

Comment: @AndrewMorton: No it's at least that size.

Comment: The largest factorial you can rely on fitting in a long long is 20! (2432902008176640000).

Comment: You don't need to calculate the actual factorial. Since `a^b mod c = a^(b mod phi(c)) mod c`. I.e., calculate the factorial up to `mod phi(c)` where `phi` is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

Comment: As for why it's giving the wrong answers: You say that n > 10^5, 10000! is around 10^456573. Compare that to the maximum value supported by `long long`.

Comment: A duplicate maybe [Calculating (a^b)%MOD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272437/calculating-abmod)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well apart exploiting some knowledge from number theory like **Nico Schertler** suggests in his comment you can do this on small ints with naive approach too.

Your problem is that your sub result is not fitting into your variables:

```
a^(b!) mod c < c
b! > c
```

The factorial result is really huge and will not fit into your small int variables without the use of bigints. But you can change the computation slightly to this:

```
  10^(3!) mod c
= 10^(1*2*3) mod c
= (((10^1 mod c)^2 mod c)^3 mod c)
```

So the idea is instead of computing the factorial by multiplying `i` iterator of a loop use `modpow` on the `a^...` sub result. This way all the sub results still fits into your variables.

**Here a small C++ code for this:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef unsigned __int32 DWORD;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD mod(DWORD a,DWORD p)
    {
    DWORD bb;
    for (bb=p;(DWORD(a)>DWORD(bb))&&(!DWORD(bb&0x80000000));bb<<=1);
    for (;;)
        {
        if (DWORD(a)>=DWORD(bb)) a-=bb;
        if (bb==p) break;
        bb>>=1;
        }
    return a;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD modadd(DWORD a,DWORD b,DWORD p)
    {
    DWORD d,cy;
    a=mod(a,p);
    b=mod(b,p);
    d=a+b;
    cy=((a>>1)+(b>>1)+(((a&1)+(b&1))>>1))&0x80000000;
    if (cy) d-=p;
    if (DWORD(d)>=DWORD(p)) d-=p;
    return d;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD modsub(DWORD a,DWORD b,DWORD p)
    {
    DWORD d;
    a=mod(a,p);
    b=mod(b,p);
    d=a-b; if (DWORD(a)<DWORD(b)) d+=p;
    if (DWORD(d)>=DWORD(p)) d-=p;
    return d;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD modmul(DWORD a,DWORD b,DWORD p)
    {
    int i;
    DWORD d;
    a=mod(a,p);
    for (d=0,i=0;i<32;i++)
        {
        if (DWORD(a&1))    d=modadd(d,b,p);
        a>>=1;
        b=modadd(b,b,p);
        }
    return d;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD modpow(DWORD a,DWORD b,DWORD p)
    {
    int i;
    DWORD d=1;
    mod(a,p);
    for (i=0;i<32;i++)
        {
        d=modmul(d,d,p);
        if (DWORD(b&0x80000000)) d=modmul(d,a,p);
        b<<=1;
        }
    return d;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD modpowfact(DWORD a,DWORD b,DWORD c) // returns a^(b!) mod c
    {
    DWORD i,y=mod(a,c);
    for (i=2;i<=b;i++)
     y=modpow(y,i,c);
    return y;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the code above returns these on my setup:

```
10^(0!) mod 1031 = 10
10^(1!) mod 1031 = 10
10^(2!) mod 1031 = 100
10^(3!) mod 1031 = 961
10^(4!) mod 1031 = 72
10^(5!) mod 1031 = 754
```

the modular arithmetic was taken from here:

- [Modular arithmetics and NTT (finite field DFT) optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18577076/2521214)

I used the slow non optimized ones so it can be compiled and run on any platform ...

Answer (score -1):

check this answer!

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/26282858/7480909
>
> I use this function to solve this problem
>
> UVA 374 - Big Mod
>
> http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=310
>
> ```
> // a^b % T
>
> // with Exponentiation by squaring (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Basic_method)
>
> // if a very large use
> // R=(unsigned long long)(R*a)%T;
>
> int restOfPot(long long a,int b,int T)
> {
>     a%=T;
>     long long R=1;
>
>     while(b)
>     {
>         if(b&1) R=(R*a)%T;
>         a=(a*a)%T;
>         b>>=1;
>     }
>
>     return int(R);
> }
> ```

Comment: This should be a comment...and it doesn't solve the problem. The problem is the OP is calling `factorial(B)` and then *passing that value around*. A good answer would show how to *not* do that.