# Overflowing remainder calculation in C++

Tags: c++, math

I want to calculate the below expression:

```
pow(2012, 17) % 3569
```

When I do this in Ruby like this, it shows 915.

```
print (2012 ** 17) % 3569
```

When I do this in C++ like this, it shows 1190.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << remainder(pow(2012, 17), 3569) << endl;
}
```

915 looks correct.
Why are they different and how to fix the C++ code?

Comment: You have to implement pow yourself using the square-and-multiply algorithm and use modulo 3569 in every step. The `pow` function works with doubles and is imprecise.

Comment: Thank you. I could re-write the script and can get the correct answer.

Comment: duplicate: [Calculating pow(a,b) mod n](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8496182/995714), [Calculating (a^b)%MOD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11272437/995714)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Goswin, I could rewrite the C++ code like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
        result *= 2012;
        result = result % 3569;
    }

    cout << result << endl;
}
```

Now it works. Thank you.

Comment: C++ source code files are not scripts (because C++ is not a scripting language, it is a compiled language).

Answer (score 0):

> Why are they different

Because C++'s [`pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) does floating-point rather than integer math.

In exact integer arithmetic, `pow(2012, 17)` would be 145,102,735,039,632,2**3**5,424,933,403,463,510,202,882,323,568,682,170,580,992.  But [the standard IEEE 754 `double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) can only approximate this value as `1.4510273503963223e+56`, or to be ultra-precise, 145,102,735,039,632,2**2**5,543,927,922,730,425,249,428,937,718,149,261,819,904, with only the first 16 sig figs correct.  Taking *this* number modulo 3569 gives 1190, as you have seen.

To get the expected result of 915, you need to use integer arithmetic.  I don't think the standard C++ library has a function for that, but it's easy to implement one.  Here's a recursive version:

```
int powmod(int base, int exponent, int modulus)
{
    if (exponent == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (exponent % 2 == 0)
    {
        int square_root = powmod(base, exponent / 2, modulus);
        return square_root * square_root % modulus;
    }
    else
    {
        return powmod(base, exponent - 1, modulus) * base % modulus;
    }
}
```

The `else if (exponent % 2 == 0)` special-casing of even exponents isn't required, but allows the algorithm to run in logarithmic rather than linear time.