# How to multiply integers larger than uint64?

Tags: c++, rsa, limit, largenumber, uint64

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
int main(void) {
    cout << std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max();
    return 0;    
}
```

The code above outputs (on my machine) `18446744073709551615`, but I'm trying to multiply  numbers that have at least 25 digits. How to properly handle a multiplication of 2 integers that are larger than `uint64`?

Comment: Red about the [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: Use one of the BigNum libraries for large integers.

Comment: You'll need to use a bignum library, like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)

Comment: Get a bigint library. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8147818/179910 My advice: avoid GMP like the plague. Actually, a quick shot of penicillin can cure the plague, so avoid GMP a lot more.

Comment: Related ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319967/exact-decimal-datatype-for-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a library that handles big numbers. Here are some of them:

- The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library

  https://gmplib.org/
- C++ Big Integer Library

  https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/
- Boost.Multiprecision

  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html