# C++ Big Int algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, integer

Hi I am doing an algorithm question require get the full result of 
5208334^2, which is 27126743055556
I was able to do it with by represent integer using Charracter array. However can we have any better way (shorter or faster)  to do that? any idea is welcome ?

Updated: 
For my case, both long long and int64 work, just that I did not cast value before return:

```
int val (int n1, n2) {
........
return (long long) n1 * n2; 

}
```

Comment: `std::vector`, so, essentially an easily resized character array.

unless you want a `std::bitset` to do some crazy magic.

Comment: Use `int64_t`. Or maybe my own [Bigint class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22004815/5987).

Comment: Tempted to close as a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8146938/179910 (among many others).

Comment: That's only 45 bits, if  27126743055556 is as high as you need to go 64bit should be fine.

Comment: __int128_t up to 40 digits

Comment: A *Charracter* array is only limited by the memory available.  Using other means means having to check if the data type has overflowed.  With *Charracter* array, you check for overflow with each digit.

Comment: This is a complete C and C++ library for arbitrary precision. https://gmplib.org/

Comment: look here [Fast bignum square computation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18465326/2521214) for simple and more advanced approaches. btw on  80386+ you can use asm 32 bit multiply it returns 64 bit result see [ALU32](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26603589/2521214)

Comment: State your measure for `better`. Representing your numbers base 5208334(base 10), the result is 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This number fits into `long long`(present in GCC and after c++11) type or `int64`(for some other compilers before c++11). Thus the simplest solution is to use this type.